# Distinguish PySpark and Pandas DataFrames in Python type hints (PyCharm)

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, type-hinting

In PyCharm it seems that the type hints do not trigger a warning if a `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` is used in place of a `pandas.DataFrame` or vice versa.

e.g. the following code will not generate any warnings at all:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame as SparkDataFrame
from pandas import DataFrame as PandasDataFrame

def test_pandas_to_spark(a: PandasDataFrame) -> SparkDataFrame:
    return a

def test_spark_to_pandas(b: SparkDataFrame) -> PandasDataFrame:
    return b.toPandas()

test_spark_to_pandas(PandasDataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]}))
```

Is this known / possible to fix?

BTW: I do have pyspark stubs installed: `pyspark-stubs==2.4.0.post2`

Comment: That seems to be expected. Neither Pandas itself nor Typeshed provides type hints for `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` so type checker won't be able to determine type of `PandasDataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3]})`.

Comment: Hmm, that's a shame. Is there a way to add them in manually on import?

Comment: Pandas are quite hard to annotate. There is some ongoing work, but it is fair from done. You could try create a dummy `partial` package, that covers only the `DataFrame` module.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a library called [`pandas-stubs`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-stubs/) which provides pandas type hints for static type checking tools to pick up on.